# The topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $C(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

We define the following set $A\subset C(\mathbb{R})$  of continuous functions:

$f\in A$ if there exist a sequence $(s_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of real numbers such that

(a)  $\dots s_{-4}<s_{-2}<0\leq s_{0}<s_{2}<s_{4}<\dots,$

(b) $\lvert s_{2i+2}-s_{2i}-1 \rvert \leq \dfrac{1}{2}, $

(c) $s_{2i+1}=(s_{2i}+s_{2i+2})/2, \: i\in\mathbb{Z};$

and a sequence of natural numbers $(n_{i})_{i \in\mathbb{Z}}$ such that

(d) $f(s_{2i})=n_{i}$,

(e) $f(s_{2i+1})=0$,

(f) $f''|_{]s_{i},s_{i+1}[}\equiv 0$ for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}$

We write $f_{(s_{2k},n_{k})_{k}}$ to denote the continuous function $f$ associated with
sequences $(s_{2k})_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ and $(n_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ given above.

$A$ is a closed subset of $C(\mathbb{R})$, where $C(\mathbb{R})$ is endowed with the compact open
topology (that is, the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$), therefore a complete separable metric space.

Indeed, if, if $(f_{j})_{j}$ is a sequence of functions in $A$ that converges to certain $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$, then each $f_{j}$  has associated sequences $\left(s_{2k}(j)\right)_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $\left(n_{k}(j)\right)_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}$ satisfying conditions $(a)-(f)$ above.

**I don't understand why : From the convergence with respect to the compact-open topology we deduce that there exist the limits $\lim_{j}s_{2k}(j)$ and $\lim_{j}n_{k}(j)$ for each $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ ? and also $f\in A$ ?**

my attempt:

I know we have to use the definition of topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, $\forall K$ compact
$$\lim_{j\to \infty}\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\lVert f_{(s_{2k}^{j},n_{k}^{j})}^{j}(x) -f(x)\rVert=0     \qquad *$$

if we replace $x$ by $s_{2k}^{j}$ to use (d) we can not conclude because we will find $s_{2k}^{j}$ in both terms of  $\quad$*

Comment: A crucial fact is that you can pinpoint for each $n$ a compact interval $K_n$ such that all $s_n(j)$ lie in $K_n$, this follows from (a)-(c). Try working with that.

Answer (score 1):

From the inequalities for the $s_i$ it follows that $s_{2i}\le \frac32(i+1)$ for $i\ge0$ and $s_{2i}\ge-\frac32i$ for $i<0$.
This means that for every $i$ the sequence $\langle s_i(j)\rangle$ has a convergent subsequence.

In addition, working on a compact interval $K=[-\frac32i,\frac23(i+1)]$ and using that the limit function $f$ is bounded on $K$ you will find that $\langle n_{2i}(j)\rangle$ takes on finitely many values.

Now using these two facts and recursion you can find a subsequence $\langle f_{j_k}\rangle$ of your given sequence such that all sequences $\langle s_i(j_k)\rangle$ and $\langle n_{2i}(j_k)\rangle$ converge.
Take an infinite set $A_0$ such that $\langle s_0(j)\rangle_{j\in A_0}$ converges,
then an infinite subset $B_0$ of $A_0$ such that $\langle n_0(j)\rangle_{j\in B_0}$ is constant, then an infinite subset $A_1$ of $B_0$ such that $\langle s_{-2}(j)\rangle_{j\in A_1}$ converges, then $\ldots$.
In the end take an infinite set $X$ such that $X\setminus A_i$ is finite for all~$i$. Then $\langle f_j\rangle_{j\in X}$ is the desired sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your comment 

if you have designated by $\langle f_{j}\rangle_{j\in X}$ that $(f_{(s_{2j},n_{j})_{j\in X}})$ (same as I know you meant by $\langle f_{j_{k}}\rangle$ that $(f_{(s_{2i}^{j_{k}},n_{i}^{j_{k}})_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}}^{j_{k}})_{k}$)

1) Can you give me the exact expression of $X$ ? (I think the expression of $X$ is $\cap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_{i}$  so that both $s_{2j}^{i}$ et $n_{j}^{i}$ converge $\forall i\in X$, and since you say $X\setminus A_{i}$ is finite ~ $i$ so $X$  is different from what I think )
  
 2) where exactly did you use the uniform topology on $K$

Comment: There is no unique $X$, you make one, recursively, by choosing, for example, $x_0=\min A_0$ and then letting $x_{n+1}$ be the first point of $A_{n+1}$ above $x_n$. I did not used much of the uniform convergence except to ensure that for each $k$ the sequence $\langle n_k(j)\rangle_j$ is bounded. You should use the uniform convergence to show that the limits of the $s_k(j)$ and $n_k(j)$ work for the limit function $f$.